# HTML CSS dropdown image in IE - dropdown icon looks outside the textbox & has whitespace.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I made a dropdown where user can type in the value & also select the value.
Problem is with the cosmetics.

Logic used:

```
 <tr>
<td align="right">
<input type="text">
</td>
<td>
<img border="0" src="dropdown.gif">
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the LINK  http://jsfiddle.net/LLPY7/1/

but when this is rendered in the IE browser, it doesnt look clean, the dropdown icon looks outside the textbox, it has a little space between them - I have tried many things but it doesnt work, any genius of javascript/css/html can help with this cosmetic issue? so it should look real.

Comment: What version(s) of IE are you using.

Comment: I would suggest redesigning the markup a bit...why are you using a table?

Answer (score 1):

Read the first comment, you need a doctype: http://www.endyourif.com/margin-0-auto-not-centering-in-internet-explorer/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN”   “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
```

Comment: No difference, still same. Thanks though.